# Plotting a step-function supply curve using python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataframe in a rather annoying structure that makes it hard for me to plot it accurately. The data looks like the following:

| Supplier | Price | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 100 |
| B | 2.25 | 125 |
| C | 2.5 | 150 |
| D | 3 | 160 |
| E | 4 | 1000 |
| F | 3.25 | 1000 |

Now what I would like to plot is an ascending supply curve that looks something like the below attached image.

[image]
Please ignore the red lines. They are just to show how the steps work.

I am quite bad with Python and from my understanding I think I need to somehow aggregate the supplies so that the cheapest amount is shown first in the most bottom left section of the curve and then the steps go upwards based on what price the next cheapest supplier can provide at and the length of the next step would then correspond to the capacity of that supplier. I hope I have made myself clear. I appreciate any help.

Best

Comment: There is no picture. Also, please share code to create the dataframe and the code you tried.

Comment: [Matplotlib has a step function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py)

Comment: I've added a picture, I hope it helps

Comment: Supplier;Price;Capacity
A;2,00;100
B;2,25;125
C;2,50;150
D;3,00;160
E;4,00;1000
F;3,25;1000

Comment: Data is in a csv above

Comment: @Mr.T I do not quite know how to get the data right for the step function. So not sure how to implement it

Comment: @Rnovice. Try reading the documentation and use the examples. Then return when you run into a specific coding problem. There is no code here, and Stack Overflow is not a free coding site.

Comment: What MadPhysicist says. There are also several assumptions here - for instance, that your data are already sorted and that an increase in capacity is accompanied by an increase in price. It also seems that the data are contained in a pandas dataframe. Whether or not these assumptions are true, we cannot know.

Answer (score 1):

With Matplotlib you can do it, use `plt.demo`, and if you check the documentation you can add more properties to the plot

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

price = np.array([2,2.25,2.5,3,4,3.25])
Capacity = np.array([100,125,150,160,1000,1000])

plt.step(price,Capacity)
plt.show()
```

Price vs Capacity Plot
[image]